# How do I retrieve data from the lat and lng tables of the Appcelerator Titantium Annotation table?

Tags: php, android, annotations, android-mapview, appcelerator

How do I retrieve data from the `lat` and `lng` tables from the MySQL DB (Appcelerator Titanium Annotation table)?  The settings below do not work :

```
var mountainView = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
latitude:e.rowData.lat,
longitude:e.rowData.lng,
title:"Nicolais Hjem",
subtitle:'I Aalborg',
pincolor:Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
animate:true,
leftView: '../images/appcelerator_small.png',
leftButton: '../iphone/appicon.png',
rightButton: Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DISCLOSURE,
myid:1,
```